# How do I configure azure web application to communicate with other ports for TCP communication?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am new to Azure and facing one issue so, trying to explain the whole scenario.

**What I want to acheive :**

I am having a TCPClient (a console application) which will send data to TCPListener (a web app hosted on azure).

**Implementation :**

1. Created one simple web application which will act as a TCP Listener. Add logs to see the received message from TCP Client.
2. Add Dockerfile
3. In dockerfile expose the port 8080 for TCP communication.
4. Publish the application on azure container repository
5. Create one console application for sending data to listener.
6. The TCPClient will connect to host my-app.azurewebsites.net and port 8080

**Issue :**

TCP Client (local console application) is not able to connect to the TCP listener. From articles I got to know that by default web app allows only 80 and 443 port. So, how do I tell my web app that it has to also work with 8080 port.

So, I read some MSDN articles and blog posts then tried following things,

1. Create virtual network
2. Create Network Security Group and add the virtual network as subnet
3. Add Inbound Security Rules in NSG.
4. Create a azure web app and assign the virtual network.
5. Set the WEBSITES_PORT in web app configuration

None of the solution works.

**Expected Output :**

TCP client application should be successfully able to connect and send data to listener.

Comment: You can't, you can only use ports 80 and 443

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the fast reply but if we have rules set in Network Security Group then can't we do that ? or is there any other way to acheive the final result ?

Answer (score 0):

- As `@Peter Bones` suggested, only 80 and 443 ports can be used by the app service and clearly detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#app-service-ports).

> [image]

- I have followed the same steps as yours and created the **app service**, **Virtual Network** and **Network security Group**. But it is only working with the port 443 but not 8080.
- It is successful when I tried with `appservicename.azurewebsites.net:<PortNumber>` as below.

[image]

-